# The next translate depends on the previous scale in a GL10 object

Tags: android, opengl-es, transformation

I set my GL10 object in this way in my 2D Android game:

```
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, -1f, 1f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

When I scale my GL10 object in this way (for example):

```
   gl.glScalef(50, 50, 0);
```

Then a call to a translate transformation such as:

```
   gl.glTranslatef(1, 1, 0f);
```

Causes a translate transformation of 50 pixel instead of 1 pixel. The same goes for a rotate transformation.

How can I do a post translate transformation without knowing previous transformations? Is it possible?

Comment: You need push/popMatrix. glScale manipulates the current matrix which then influences glTranslate. By using proper nesting, you can solve that.

Comment: If I push the matrix, then I scale, then I pop and then I translate I apply the translate to the previous non scaled matrix. I already use push and pop to draw every object with its matrix, but this scale and translate operations are used in the draw routine of one object.

Comment: I see the problem now. You want the scaling to apply to just drawing, but if you think of it in terms of matrices, you'll see that's impossible. You can't have transformed the object coordinates with glScale (a multiplication with a scaling matrix) and then that operation to not be used in consecutive operations. 2 solutions are possible: 1) move the camera closer, you can achieve a similar effect to the scale, 2) store the scale factor in the object, so that you can apply the correct post-scale operations (or just scale the object's vertex coordinates and don't bother with glScale).

Comment: I was only interested in whether it was possible or not, and you answered me, thank you. If you write this in an answer, I will choose it as best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not `OpenGL` guru but what I used is changing `vertices` like:

Lets say we had:

```
    vertices = new float[12];

    vertices[0] = -0.25f;
    vertices[1] = -0.25f;
    vertices[2] = 0.0f;

    vertices[3] = -0.25f;
    vertices[4] = 0.25f;
    vertices[5] = 0.0f;

    vertices[6] = 0.25f;
    vertices[7] = -0.25f;
    vertices[8] = 0.0f;

    vertices[9] = 0.25f;
    vertices[10] =0.25f;
    vertices[11] =0.0f;
```

So to change zoom in I used:

```
            gl.glPushMatrix();

            ...   

    vertices[0] = -0.25f - 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;// dummy increase index 
    vertices[1] = -0.25f - 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;

    vertices[3] = -0.25f - 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;
    vertices[4] = 0.25f + 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;


    vertices[6] = 0.25f + 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;
    vertices[7] = -0.25f - 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;

    vertices[9] = 0.25f + 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;
    vertices[10] =0.25f + 1.75f *(mGameRange - distance)/mGameRange;


            vertexBuffer.clear();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

            ...

            gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting your scale call inside of a glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() and having your translate call after the pop.

[good discussion here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/130172-glPushMatrix%28%29-glPopMatrix%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

What i've found is that if you want the translations to be separate you have to translate in the opposite direction for example after finishing a translation.

```
        gl.glTranslatef(position.X, position.Y, 0);
        gl.glDrawArrays(...); //first triangle 
        gl.glTranslatef(-position.X, -position.Y, 0); // note how they are negative instead of positive
        gl.glDrawArrays(...); //second triangle
```

in this code the second triangle will be drawn at 0,0,0 and the first will be drawn at position.X, position.Y , 0. this tends to work for me but i still recommend pushing and popping the matrix before and after doing these translations.